# Unnecessary constraint in quantum statistics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, photons, superposition, bose-einstein-condensate

In deriving Bose-Einstein or Fermi-Dirac distribution, if $N_n$ is no. of entities with energy $E_n$, then two the constraints for a system with N particles and total energy E are:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}N_n=N $

2.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}N_nE_n=E$

Second constraint is obviously needed however the first condition seems unnecessary to me since why cant we have an entity (boson) which is in a superposition of two states and hence will be part of two terms in condition 2 and 1 as well making 1 false. If we remove first constraint we will have a photon like behaviour for all entities which is further an expected outcome of QM.

All the same, the expression derived using conjunction of these constraints has been derived by method of detailed balance in QM by Eisberg-Resnick so that both constraints must be relevant . In that case would such a superposition which I am contriving be unstable and collapse to one of the constituent eigenstate?

Comment: The short answer is that you aren't doing this perfectly quantum mechanically. You are doing classical stat mech but with a discrete set of states obtained via QM. Both your equations are also required for the grand cannonical ensemble of a classical ideal gas as well.

Comment: Why isn't it perfect, afaik there are unique expressions for bose-einstein and fermi-dirac stats and they are derived im Griffiths using these constraints

Comment: The results you obtain are correct, but the derivation isn't "fully quantum". It's mostly classical, it has the same quantum input really as all the other stat mech you've done with non-degenerate gases.

Comment: I checked in Kerson Huang, same constraints are used @jacob1729

Answer (score 0):

Statistical mechanics, when combined with quantum mechanics, leads to quantization(first kind of quantization in the above case), thus particles have certain energy with some conservation of quantities like here is the number of particles in the system. This system is considered a closed system and even with photons you know that within system photons can create particles and antiparticles, therefore, the number of photons is not conserved. The first constraint is obviously the conservation of particles within the system, but why do we need it, the second constraint should be enough which is actually not true because you may have a system that may contain zero energy level.

Even particles may be in a superposition of states, this does not help in obtaining the right statistics.